# Omit last element in comma-separated list

Tags: python

I'm writing a tagging system.  The user enters a number of tags:

```
abc, def, ghi,
```

But if they use a trailing comma, the code thinks there are 4 tags, not three.

In my code, I write:

```
if "tags" in request.POST:
    tags = request.POST["tags"]
    tag_list = [Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = tag.lstrip())[0] for tag in tags.split(",")]
```

A tag ' ' gets created in this instance.  How can I alter the code to ignore any entry that is I suppose len(str) = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for tag in tags.split(",") if tag.strip()
```

Comment: The strip is not a mutating method so you still have the whitespace on the tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = "first, second, third,"
>>> y = [ele for ele in x.split(',') if ele]
>>> y
['first', ' second', ' third']
```

Using the fact that non empty strings return `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter(), like so:

```
def f(x): return x != ''

filter( f, tag_list )
```

Comment: maybe is better a lambda there

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use lstrip() rather than strip() for processing the tags? What if the user enters `abc , def`; do you really want to allow a tag `"abc "` with a trailing space?

If you really want to strip the tags on both sides (which I think you do), then it's a simple matter of doing that and then omitting the empty ones:

```
try: # EAFP
    tags = (tag.strip() for tag in request.POST['tags'].split(','))
    tag_list = [Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = tag)[0] for tag in tags if tag]
    # 'if tag' is the operative "filtering" bit
except KeyError: pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tag_list = [tag.lstrip() for tag in tags.split(",") if len(tag.lstrip())>0]
```

will generate the tag_list without the empty character.

Rest should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all your `tags` processing in once place, so you don't have to
call `tag.lstrip()` inside `get_or_create(name = ...)`:

```
if "tags" in request.POST:
    tags = request.POST["tags"]
    tags = (tag.lstrip() for tag in tags.split(',') if tag.strip())
    tag_list = [Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = tag)[0] for tag in tags]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tags are actually set individually in the same variable instead of as a string list you have the option of just writing:

```
filter(len, map(str.strip, request.POST.getlist("keys")))
```

Without having to parse a string list manually.